# Dust PHP tries to call functions if a function name is passed in context

Tags: php, templates, dust.js

I'm using the PHP fork of dustjs: http://cretz.github.io/dust-php/

The following code works fine:

```
$compiled = $dust->compile('Hi {name}.');
echo $dust->renderTemplate($compiled, ['name' => 'John Doe']);
```

But the following fails:

```
echo $dust->renderTemplate($compiled, ['name' => 'link']);
```

with this error:

```
PHP Warning:  link() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, object given in /var/www/grallo2/vendor/dust-php/dust-php/src/Dust/Evaluate/Evaluator.php on line 342
```

It seems dust is trying to execute PHP functions. Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: try this: $dust->compile('Hi {name}.', 'TEMPLATE1');
print $dust->render('TEMPLATE1', ['name' => 'link']);

Comment: @num8er that didn't work.